# Is it valid to delete a constraint that is linear combination of other constraints?

Tags: optimization, constraints

I have an optimization problem in which one constraint is linear combination of the other two constraints like this:

$$
(1) A+B \le D \\
(2) E+F \le D \\
(3) A+B+E+F \le 2D
$$

Is it valid to delete constraint ${(3)}$, since it is a linear combination of constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't provide any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid to delete constraint (3) since it is redundant with the other two. In some computer modelling languages, though, it can sometimes be useful to keep redundant constraints in the model to help reduce the search space.

Comment: I would say that it's more than just an issue of computer modeling languages.  If a set of, say, linear constraints is not satisfiable, then $1 < 0$ can be derived from them, but it may take a lot of effort.

Comment: Well, if a set of linear constraints is not satisfiable then I'd argue that all of the constraints are redundant to $1<0$ and can be removed ;)

Comment: Agreed, provided $1<0$ is already part of your input.  In general, identifying a minimal subset of unsatisfiable constraints may be expensive.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of formalism to the answer, we can think of the answer to this in terms of set relations. Let our initial feasible region be $$X =\{x \in \mathbb {R}^4|x_1 + x_2 \leq D, x_3 + x_4 \leq D,x_1 + x_2 +x_3+x_4\leq 2D\}$$ and the new feasible region be $$Y =\{x \in \mathbb {R}^4|x_1 + x_2 \leq D, x_3 + x_4 \leq D\}.$$ We want to know if $$X=Y.$$ Let us take any element $x \in X.$ It is immediate that it must also be in $Y$. Therefore, $$X \subseteq  Y.$$ Now, take any element $y \in Y$. Can you show that it must also be in $X$? If you do that you've also shown $$Y \subseteq  X.$$ These two results show that the feasible regions are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete $(3)$. On the other hand, $(3)$ combined with either of them does not imply the third one.